# Excel: Multiple if statements to populate cells between two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image: can someone pleas help with this]

I understand how to populate one of these cells using an `=(if(and))`, but I cannot figure out how to populate a desired range of cells between the start time and deadline time. For example, for task `abc12345`, I want to highlight cells that will populate in the `9:30am`, `10:00am`, `10:30am` cells. Is this possible?

Comment: For task abc12345 only two cell will be populated 10:00 & 10:30 since  start time is 09:55 & Deadline is 11:00 & so that both will highlight !

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention highlighting, I will offer a solution that uses conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=AND(E$1>$C2,$D2>K$1)
```

Which should be applied to the following range: `E3:K5`

Assumptions:

1) The list of times is on row `1`

2) Start Time and Deadline are in columns `C` and `D`

3) All times are actually formatted as Time and are not strings